# ajax tool kit integration problem

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

how can i register my ajax tool kit, i downloaded a 3.5.40412.0 version(for 2008 and 2.0 dot net ) and integrated it as per the direction but after putting script manager to aspx page it says it doesn't recognize the tag do i need to register it if so then where and how can i register this to my project 
is it any thing to do with web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your, keeping existing elements, web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
   <assemblies> 
 <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
   </assemblies>
</compilation>
<pages>
  <controls>
<add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajax" />   
  </controls> 
</pages>
```

The example i gave is assuming the dll will be packaged and deployed to your bin directory.  If you are GAC'ing let me know and i will update.

Comment: i did the same explained by ou bu of no avail it's sill not recognizing the script manager tag on aspx page 
any suggestions

Comment: Post your code samples.  Make sure your script manager is ajax:ScriptManager